# Lucee SSL Certificate being dropped

Tags: ssl, lucee

An installed SSL certificate (via Lucee server admin > Services > SSL Certificates) keeps getting lost. We enter the target host name click LIST, see the cert and click INSTALL.

It's all fine for a few weeks the suddenly it just disappears (and our 2 way SSL automation dies). We have no idea why it suddenly just goes though, the cert is valid for another year and there doesn't appear to be a way of manually removing the certs so we are at a loss.

We also don't know where that install process actually stores the cert (in a file, Database, memory) in order to try and monitor it a bit better.

Whats confusing me even more is this is happening across 3 servers (Win 2012).

Each time this happens all we've done is reinstall the cert to Lucee (its already on the cert store on the windows box & the java store) and that seems to resolve it.

Any ideas on why it's happening and how to stop it from happening again?